# compare two strings in rdd scala and got exception Task not serializable

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have rdd of two strings JoindStrings: RDD[(String, String)] and I need to calculate the similarity between each pair of strings
I tried this:

```
val similarPairsRdd: RDD[(String, String, Double)] = 
    JoindStrings.map(x => (x._1, x._2, getSimilarity(x._1, x._2)))
```

The function `getSimilarity` takes two strings and return double
I have an exception in thread "main"

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable

Also, i tried `JoindStrings.map.collect()(x => ...` but it gives me array not rdd
Is there any solution for this exception?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by name, `getSimilarity` probably doesn't use any fields from your "main" class, but it still requires a reference to it to be called on so Spark has to serialize it. Extract it to a separate `object`.

Answer (score 0):

For operation over RDD, I think the function getSimilarity needs to be an UDF. Use spark.functions._ package to create an UDF.

You can directly use getSimilarity function if you operate over Dataset.

```
val joindStrings : Dataset[(String, String)] = .. source of dataset 
val similarPairsRdd  = joindStrings.map { x => (x._1, x._2, getSimilarity(x._1, x._2)) }
```